# Multiple jQuery loads breaks plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins

Multiple jquery loads from clients breaks plugin

Made a jsbin here - http://jsbin.com/useyis/5/edit

Let's tackle this problem

```
var $customname = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then calling

```
$customname('div').yourpluginname
```

works but it is not a solution as it will break other plugins using `$` instead of `jQuery`.

Comment: Plugins that are using "$" instead of "jQuery" on intialization are very rare. And if there is one, that can be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, I came up with this

We save a function on the window object and then call that with the cached jquery object

solution - http://jsbin.com/useyis/14/edit